# Nombre de columna es un número

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, tablas, orm

Estoy usando Laravel y quiero copiar una tabla Semana la cual muestro a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
        // Aquí capturo el registro del día Lunes
        $dia_lunes = Semana::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Lunes')->first();

        // Aquí estoy recorriendo del siete al 20 porque esos son los nombres de las columnas.
        // Estos números representan las horas del día.
        for ($i = 7; $i <= 20; $i++) {

            // Aquí estoy actualizando la tabla Perturbada con la información de la tabla Semana.
            Perturbada::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Lunes')->update([$i => $dia_lunes->$i]);
        }

        // De aquí en adelante repito lo mismo para los demás días.

        $dia_martes = Semana::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Martes')->first();

        for ($i = 7; $i <= 20; $i++) {
            Perturbada::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Martes')->update([$i => $dia_martes->$i]);
        }

        $dia_miercoles = Semana::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Miercoles')->first();

        for ($i = 7; $i <= 20; $i++) {
            Perturbada::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Miercoles')->update([$i => $dia_miercoles->$i]);
        }

        $dia_jueves = Semana::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Jueves')->first();

        for ($i = 7; $i <= 20; $i++) {
            Perturbada::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Jueves')->update([$i => $dia_jueves->$i]);
        }

        $dia_viernes = Semana::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Viernes')->first();

        for ($i = 7; $i <= 20; $i++) {
            Perturbada::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Viernes')->update([$i => $dia_viernes->$i]);
        }

        $dia_sabado = Semana::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Sabado')->first();

        for ($i = 7; $i <= 20; $i++) {
            Perturbada::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Sabado')->update([$i => $dia_sabado->$i]);
        }
        dd();
```

El problema que tengo es que no se está copiando nada en la otra tabla y creo que la razón de esto es porque el nombre de las columnas son números, ya que si por ejemplo yo hago:

- dia_lunes->8
- dia_lunes->'8'
- dia_lunes->{8}
- dia_lunes->{'8'}

Si trato de usar estas variables obtengo null o me da error. Este es el código y finalmente una imagen del error. Espero que puedan ayudarme. Desde ya gracias.

```
        $dia_lunes = Semana::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Lunes')->first();
        dd($dia_lunes->8);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si pruebas así `$dia_lunes = Semana::where('codigo', 'T00040458')->where('dia', 'Lunes')->first(); $ocho = 8; dd($dia_lunes->$ocho);` que te devuelve? O así tambien puede ser `$ocho = '8'; dd($dia_lunes->$ocho);`

Comment: Amigo ya he tratado esas dos maneras también. La idea que tenía con las columnas como números era usar un for para recorrer las columnas del 7 al 20. Hice eso mismo guardando los números en una variable $i.

Comment: Me sirvió la solución del alias, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una salida sería poniendo un alias a cada columna:

```php
$dia_lunes = Semana::select('8 as ocho')
    ->where('codigo', 'T00040458')
    ->where('dia', 'Lunes')
    ->first();
```

Y acceder al valor del alias:

```
$dia_lunes->ocho;
```

Comment: @DeivisCervantesPuello podrías probar también si te funciona crear accessors y mutators. Si es así, ya podrías manejarte con los atributos del modelo y olvidarte de los nombres de columna con números.